# How to find mouse binding in Emacs for mouse-5 events?

Tags: emacs, mouse, gnu

In Gnu Emacs v23, I'd like to find out what is bound to mouse events like the following:

```
<mouse-5>
<double-down-mouse-5>
<double-mouse-5>
<triple-down-mouse-5>
<triple-mouse-5>
```

If it was a keystroke, I would just do `M-x describe-key` but what can I do for a mouse stoke that I cannot reliably produce, that is I don't know how to create these events consistently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`describe-bindings` gives me a buffer with a list of all keybindings defined. Apart from others, it offers:

```
<C-mouse-5> mwheel-scroll
<S-mouse-5> mwheel-scroll
<mouse-5>   mwheel-scroll
```

where `mwheel-scroll` is apparently the mousewheel scrolling function :-)